# Including references without bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing

These steps are followed when a new citation is added into a manuscript:

1. Add a new reference to the references file (e.g. `myref.bib`)
2. Add a citation to the new reference into the main tex file (e.g. `paper.tex`)
3. `latex paper.tex`
4. `bibtex myref.bib`
5. `latex paper.tex`
6. `latex paper.tex`

Is there another way to achieve the above-mentioned process in three steps as follows:

1. Add new reference to `myref.bib`
2. Add citation to the new reference to `paper.tex`
3. `latex paper.tex`

Comment: One possible solution may be using `makefile` or scripts, etc. However, I wonder whether there is a solution that uses only latex.

Comment: The reason that BibTeX is used here is that it's a dedicated tool focussed on extracting information from the `.bib` file and sorting the results. TeX isn't the best language for doing that, so while it is possible, to date no one has to my knowledge tried to implement all of BibTeX directly in TeX.

Comment: A partial solution is given by the `usebib` by Enrico Gregorio

Comment: You may also have a look at the package [amsrefs](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amsrefs) which does not use `bibtex`.

Comment: Could you say *why* you want this? That is, what specific problems do you experience using the current workflow? Because there may be a solution you haven't considered but it depends on what the problem is.

Comment: @cfr, the problem is that I am using TexWorks since it has 'jump to source/pdf' feature, but TexWorks does not have keyboard shortcuts for selecting typesetting tools. Hence, I have to use mouse to select `pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex...`. Using `amsrefs` is a good workaround because running only `pdflatex` is enough.

Comment: You should look at `arara` which allows you to specify multiple things to do on a single run. But can't you customise the shortcuts? I think the jump feature is a very common one, by the way, so not a reason to stick with an editor if it doesn't suit you in other ways.